# List pattern finder in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I'm trying to make a python list pattern finder. My fisrt idea was to take the first value in a list and then find the next occurence of that same value. That would then be the potential pattern sequence length, and I would then check if the numbers from the first number to the second one equals the values after the second number in the range of the potential pattern sequence length.

For example:

If I have this list

```
[1, 2, 6, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8]
```

It would then take the first number `1` and take the index of the second `1` in the list minues the index of the first one. So `3 - 0 = 3`, that would then be the pattern length. Then it would check if `list[:3] == list[3:3 + pattern length]`. And so on until the patterns did not match. The final result would then be `[[3, [1, 2, 6]], [2, [7, 8]]]`. It would be better to have a dictionary as output, but if two patterns are the same a dictionaru won't work since it can't have two of the same keys.

I found this method to not be very efffective and I either didn't completly succeed with my function, so I wonder if someone can help me with another pattern finder function idea or if there is a python module for this.

I found this online: https://regex101.com/r/Vdhjld/1, which does exactly what I want, but my actuall list is very large and using that one takes to much time. Any ideas on what I should do?

Please comment if description is unclear

Comment: The approach you described is wrong. For eg: `[1,2,1,3,1,2,1,3]` the result should be `[[2,[1,2,1,3]]]` right? Instead of `[[1,[1,2]],[1,[1,3]],[1,[1,2]],[1,[1,3]]]`

Comment: What would you expect if it was something like `[1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5]`? Also what happens if numbers are the same? e.g. `[1, 1, 1, 1]` is the pattern `[1, [1], 1, [1],...]` or `[4, [1, 1, 1, 1]]`?

Comment: @Raj sorry if I explained bad, yes the result should be ```[[2,[1,2,1,3]]]``` and that's why my approch is dumb.

Comment: @DenFulaAnkungen So you are not searching for the longest pattern, but rather the shortest pattern?

Comment: @LeoE sorry, no. The output should probabbly be ```[[2, [1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 5]]]```. I will update my answer. Sorry for the condusion, I didn't look through the list very thorough. Or maybe it could be ```[[2, [[2, [1, 2]], 4, 5]]```

Comment: So just to clarify: `[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]` Would result in `[1, [1, 2], 2, [1, 2, 3]]`? And do the patterns need to be sorted in order of occurrence in the list? So would `[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2]` have to be `[1, [1, 2], 2, [1, 2, 3], 1, [1, 2]]`? Or would [2, [1, 2], 2, [1, 2, 3]]` be okay as well?

Comment: @LeoE It would have to be `[1, [1, 2], 2, [1, 2, 3], 1, [1, 2]]` . Since I need to be able to decode it to the original list.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing this as an answer, because it is to detailed for a comment.
I think you should first be clear about your requirements, this is not a trivial question and there are multiple solutions to your problem especially, if it is a long list.

Some examples for problems that might occur:

Lets first take the following list:

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

There are multiple (all correct) solutions to finding patterns in this list:

1. `[3, [1, 2], 1, [3], 2, [1, 2] , 1, [3, 1, 2, 1]`
2. `[1, [1, 2], 2, [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 1, [1, 2, 1]]`
3. `[1, [1], 2, [2, 1], 2, [2, 3, 1, 2, 1]]`
4. `[2, [1, 2], 2, [1, 2, 3, 1, 2], 1 [1]]`

Which one of these is supposed to be the "correct" answer to your question? Even if we say, the one with the longest subsequence we still have three different solutions left. And this is only with a list length of 15 and only three different numbers, the larger the list gets the more different solutions might be in your list. The only solution I could think of is to choose one solution arbitrarily by searching for the longest common sequence, removing it from the list and repeat that until the list is empty. This might pose problems to your sorting, however, and might be very slow. If anybody has a better approach I'm happy to hear it.

It got stuck in my head and I had nothing else to do, so I just tried it out, it is unsorted, you'd have to do that, but it extracts the longest common patterns. It is however recursive, so I don't know, if it works for your long list, but it might give you an idea on how to solve it. I do not think, that this is the fastest possible way by far, it is just one way to handle it. Just use it as an idea and write your own code with this in mind. Here now comes the (rather long) code:

```
test = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4]
test_1 = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
test_2 = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2]
test_3 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]

def pattern_finder(mylist, pattern):
    matches = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(mylist):
        if mylist[i] == pattern[0] and mylist[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern:
            matches.append(i)
            i += len(pattern)
        else:
            i+=1
    return matches

def get_patterns(list_input, p=None):
    if type(list_input[0]) != list:
        list_input = [list_input]
    result = []
    for list_in in list_input:
        if len(set(list_in)) == 1:
            result.append([1,list_in])
            continue
        n = len(list_in)
        if n == 1:
            result.append(list_in[0])
            continue
        p_len = p
        if p == None:
            p_len = int(n/2)
        lhs = 0
        rhs = lhs + p_len
        list_split = list_in
        if p_len <= 1:
            result.append([1, list_in])
            continue
        found = False
        while lhs < n - p_len and not found:
            rhs = lhs + p_len
            while rhs <= n-p_len:
                if list_in[lhs:lhs+p_len] == list_in[rhs:rhs+p_len]:
                    found = True
                    matches = pattern_finder(list_in, list_in[lhs:lhs+p_len])
                    list_split = []

                    for i,m in enumerate(matches):
                        if i == 0 and m != 0:
                            list_split.append(list_in[0:m])
                            continue
                        if i == len(matches)-1:
                            if m+p_len != n:
                                list_split.append(list_in[m+p_len:])
                            continue
                        if m+p_len != matches[i+1]:
                            list_split.append(list_in[m+p_len:matches[i+1]])
                    result.append([len(matches), list_in[lhs:lhs+p_len]])
                    break
                rhs += 1
            lhs += 1
        if list_split == []:
            continue
        if not found:
            result += get_patterns(list_split, p_len-1)
        else:
            result += get_patterns(list_split)
    return result

print("Result:", get_patterns(test))
```

Comment: Thank you so much and for dedicating so much time to this, I'm reallt greatful. I will defininetly take a look and try to understand everything in your code. To be honest I don't know if I will understand it all, but thank you. I tried running it on my full list, it probably works but it's still running after 20 min. Thanks again

Comment: Longest repeated sequence can be find in O(n) using suffix trees. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem